# Pixel-based graphics in linux terminal application

Tags: c++, linux, graphics

I'm developing a C++ application which will run on a headless server and keep track of some statistics. The application will run in a terminal in a screen session so that I can login over SSH and check those statistics.

Now, what I want to do, is display plots of various data. For that I need pixel-per-pixel access of course, which is not possible with ncurses or S-Lang. I found out about [DirectFB](https://github.com/DirectFB/directfb) (and it's C++ wrappers [DFB++](http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Projects%2FDFB%2B%2B) & [++DFB](http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Projects%2F%2B%2BDFB)), but can't seem to find conclusive evidence if it is possible to draw graphics with it inside a terminal.

Is DirectFB the way to go? Will it work fine inside a screen session without creating extra windows? If not, is there any library out there that can achieve what I want?

**Edit:** Ideally, I would of course prefer a library that has some kind of widget support as well, so that I don't have to create tons of classes to emulate text fields/scrollbars/...

Comment: I remember SDL also being able to draw on consoles, which was a funny happening back then as I did not expect to see my ray tracings on a full screen terminal.

Comment: why don't you use X with network forwarding? Performances reasons?

Comment: @ akappa Would that work if I disconnect from the remote server and login from somewhere else later? Would the window get properly forwarded? Even if that would work, I would still prefer not cluttering my desktop with extra windows, the application is running inside a terminal and I'd like it to stay in there.

Comment: @Darhuuk: but it's very unlikely that an application tied with libraries that accesses the underlying hardware (such as DirectFB or SDL) for drawing would work on a ssh'd terminal :). I'd try something based on X + screen first

Comment: @akappa Good point, but hence my question of course :).

Comment: so, as far as I can see, you could either use something à-la-ncurses (which just draws on VT100-or-better terminals) or something based on X forwarding, for full graphics handling. Which kind of drawings you'd like to plot? Something purely terminal-based would have a rather crude plotting ability...

Comment: Oh, uh... that domain appears to have a new owner

Comment: Ha, thanks for the heads up :). Fixed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make your application have a **web interface**. You could use e.g. [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/) or [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) to make your application an HTTP server (or you could make it a FastCgi application), and use SVG (perhaps with Javascript and Ajax tricks) to display vector graphics (or generate a pixel-based PNG or JPEG or GIF image; there are several libraries for that).

I don't think that DirectFB works with SSH, and I believe it is becoming deprecated (for example GTK3 don't support it anymore).

You might also generate [Gnu Plot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) graphics (by generating the appropriate commands), but that is not very interactive.

I don't think that making graphics thru ssh without X make sense, unless you want only ASCII art (which I believe is not the right way for your needs).

Comment: yeah, this is the natural and most do-able approach

Comment: Those two frameworks look very nice indeed, especially Wt. And I already have nginx running on the server, so could use that to proxy to the application.

Comment: Your CGI to generate the statistics graphs may just be a simple shell script calling gnuplot. I'd hack something along these lines first.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Hm, ideally I'd want around 4 updates per second of multiple graphs (though they can be overlaid), so that might be a bit wastefull, no? Still, premature optimization is evil I guess :).

Comment: @Darhuuk: I'm talking about something you can hack in 15 minutes.

Comment: web based is too slow and require dependency on network and browser. Try using OpenGL on linux.